# Updating an image in laravel does not save to DB, only saves when adding new record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the form of a service where a name, description, and photo is required. When adding a new service the form works fine, everything is saved in the database.

Problem is when I want to change the photo and upload a new one its not working.

### **Here is my controller method **, for both adding and updating service

```
public function post(ServiceRequest $request, Service $service)
{
    $service = Service::firstOrNew(['id' => $request->get('id')]);

    $service->id = $request->get('id');
    $service->name = $request->get('name');
    $service->description = $request->get('description');
    $image = $request->file('photo')->store('services/');
    $service->photo = $image;

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $image = $request->file('photo');
        $name = time() . $service->name . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/services');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    }
    if ($request->has('photo')) {
        $image = $request->file('photo');
    }

    $service->save();

    Alert::success('Service Saved');
    return redirect()->back();
    // dd($service);
}
```

I need some assistance with updating the image and removing an old one that was added on update record.

Comment: Do you use 2 different forms for creating and editing?  would be good to see the html.

Comment: You are not setting the `$image` on the `$service->photo` after changing the `$image`

Comment: @JohnHalsey , I am using one view to add and edit

Comment: So the problem would seem to be with your `if ($request->has('photo')) ` line.  I would personally split the methods up so you had one for saving, and one for updating that accepted an ID.  It'll much easier to debug / maintain.